# SharePoint development without SharePoint client SDK?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sdk

I tried accessing SharePoint site using CSOM (C# with HttpClient and WebClient) but there also for authentication I need to use SharePoint Client SDK.

Is there any way so that I can perform SharePoint operations without using `SharePoint.Client` and `SharePoint.Client.Runtime` DLL on client machine (Non-SharePoint environment)?

Answer (score 2):

**SharePoint Client SDK** is need for **CSOM** only. If you don't want to use **SharePoint Client SDK**, then you can use **REST API**. For accessing **REST API**, you do not need **SharePoint Client SDK**. Have a look on the following example using  `HttpWebRequest` & **REST API**.

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("Site URL/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(List Name')/items");

 endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
 endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
 NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
 endpointRequest.Credentials = cred;
 HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse) endpointRequest.GetResponse();
 try {
     WebResponse webResponse = endpointRequest.GetResponse();
     Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
     StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
     string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
     JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(response);
     JArray jarr = (JArray) jobj["d"]["results"];
     foreach(JObject j in jarr) {
         Console.WriteLine(j["Title"] + " " + j["Body"]);
     }

     responseReader.Close();
     Console.ReadLine();


 } catch (Exception e) {
     Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
     Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Above [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/roji.joy/working-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-in-a-c-sharp-managed-code/) has a dependency with **Json.NET** library for parsing response. You can use any library to parse your response but **SharePoint Client SDK** is not needed here.

All **CSOM** features are almost in **REST API.** For CRUD operation in list, you can have a look on my following article.

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: I am trying the same code. But in line HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse) endpointRequest.GetResponse(); giving me error for 403 forbidden. Passing the correct credential

Comment: Can you try without domain `NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");` as your environment is SharePoint online.

Comment: Getting the same error. I guess problem with header? Do we need to pass any more header?

Comment: for **GET** request `application/json;odata=verbose` is enough. let me check.

Comment: Yes you need to pass more extra headers. Try it from fiddler at first. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7474077/1294606